# Add Service Reference creates datasource... sometimes

Tags: c#, wcf

So there exists a WCF Service (called "UserWS") that I've created.

In Website A, when I "Add Service Reference...", the system creates a User object in the object browser.  I can use that UserWS.User object to make User objects that agree with the guts of what's happening in the Web Service.  Life is good.

In Website B, when I "Add Service Reference...", the system creates identical code except for the User object. It doesn't make one at all. Life isn't so good.

I've made sure that the options in both "Add Service Reference..." dialogs are identical.  The property pages for the projects are identical. Can someone point me in the direction of what I'm missing?

Comment: VS2013.  Same for both projects. http://sdrv.ms/19vxRW7

Comment: That's a great question... that's just what VS put in there. That is Website A where life is good, so I suspect it's part of the phenomenon. I re-Added the service ref and VS recreates it.  http://sdrv.ms/1a7GetL

Comment: I clicked identically on both sides. Add Service Reference, picked the same URL, same options. Here's the Configure Service Reference dialog: http://sdrv.ms/1cY3oRO

Comment: I also just realized I used "web service" in the description above.  It's actually a WCF service.  I'm sure that makes a difference, though I'm not sure how. :)  Fixed the original question...

Comment: I've fixed it. MCP wont let me post a solution to my own question for another 6 hours though. Had to uncheck Reuse Types in the Configure Service Ref box.  Will post solution tomorrow on it. Next time I have this issue, I'll surely find it with the Google-Fu and feel stupid.  Thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it's not much of a solution, but it worked (this time). In Website B when I DE-select the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" box, under Configure Service Reference, it recreates the reference WITH the User data contract from the WCF service. life is good in Website B.

I am reminded of some of the greatest words ever by Captain Montgomery Scott "The more they overtake the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain."